# What senior officers have their own private office/workspace?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager

The Captain has the ready room. Chief Medical Officers have their own desk/office areas in sick bay. And I believe ship's Counselor has their own office. Do any other senior officers have dedicated workspaces? For example, does the Chief Engineer has his own office? Or Chief of Security/Tactical Officer?

As space constraints vary among different class ships, this would likely influence the answer. So let's narrow it down to Galaxy class and Voyager's class starships for now.

Comment: Probably depends on the ship and era. Kirk's ready room, if any, was never shown. Mention was made of Scotty and Geordi's respective offices, but I don't recall any such mention of Tucker's, Torres's or O'Brien's. We have no idea where most non-Federation ships are concerned. As asked, this is quite a broad question - I suggest at least narrowing it to the main series ships.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The StarTrek.com website maintains an office listing for many main characters.

### Enterprise-D

**[Jean-Luc Picard (Captain, USS Enterprise)](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/picard-jean-luc)**
**Office:** *Enterprise: Deck 1 Ready Room, adjoining Main Bridge*

**[Geordi la Forge (Chief Engineer)](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/la-forge-Geordi#sthash.uU0s1E0w.dpuf)**
**Office:** *Enterprise: adjacent to Warp Core, Deck 36 Main Engineering*

**[Beverly Crusher (Chief Medical Office)](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/crusher-beverly)**
**Office:** *Formerly, Enterprise-D: Deck 12/Room 1629*

**[Guinan (Civilian Lounge Hostess)](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/guinan)**
**Office:** *U.S.S. Enterprise: Adjacent to Ten-Forward lounge, Deck 10*

**[Deanna Troi (Ship's Counselor)](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/troi)**
**Office:** *Formerly, Enterprise Deck 8.*

---

### Voyager

**[Kathyrn Janeway (Captain, USS Voyager)](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/kathryn-janeway#sthash.J40Jl4UZ.dpuf)**
**Office:** *(2371-2378) Voyager, Deck 1 Ready Room adjoining Bridge*

**[The Doctor (Chief Medical Officer)](http://www.startrek.com/database_article/the-doctor)**
**Office:** *(through 2378) Adjoining Sickbay on Deck 5, U.S.S. Voyager*

**Chakotay (XO, Voyager)** has an office aboard the Voyager. It appears to be on Deck 2.

[image]

**Tuvok (Chief of Security, Voyager)** has an office on Deck 6, proximate to the brig.

[image]

**B'Elanna Torres (Chief Engineer, Voyager)** has an office that's directly adjacent to main engineering.

[image]

Comment: Star Trek:TOS:The Naked Time: "SCOTT: I can't. He's hooked everything through the main panel in there. Get up to **my office** and pull the plans for this bulkhead. The only way to get that door open is to cut through these wall circuits here."

Comment: @Politank-Z - "*let's narrow it down to Galaxy class and Voyager's*" said the OP

Comment: @Valorum Fair enough.

Comment: I think you have the wrong girl in your last picture. She looks more like Seven of Nine to me than Torres. :)

Comment: Looking closer at the picture did you pick it because it shows Torres leaving her office? I can't really tell if it is her in that doorway and I don't know the show well enough to know if that is main engineering... At first I thought you made an honest mistake with the photo, but the odds are definitely better I missed something in the photo.

Comment: @Erik - I just picked it because it's one of the only pictures that shows her office from the rear (looking across the desk) rather than from the front (looking toward the warp core). The fact that Seven is in her office was mere coincidence.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense, so Seven is working at Torres' desk.

Comment: @Erik - Actually she's sabotaging the ship '*at Torres' desk*', but who's counting?

Comment: You forgot Data's workshop, where he created Lol and interfaced with Locutus.

Comment: @DrSheldon - Those don't appear to be his exclusive spaces, notwithstanding that he's the Science Officer and that all the labs are his.